# NHibernate self referencing query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

How do you write this in NHibernate?

```
criteria
    .CreateAlias( "CreatorObject.LastCreated", "me" )
    .Add( Restrictions.Eq( this, "me" ) );
```

Edit: something like this without using sql

Where there are two tables TypeA and TypeB where typeB creates typeA objects and keeps a reference to the last object created.

```
criteria
.Add( Restrictions.IdEq( Projections.SqlProjection( "(Select LastCreated From Creators Where Creators.Id = CreatorId) as MasterId", new[] { "MasterId" }, new[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 } ) ) );
```

Comment: What SQL would you be expecting from this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have something like

```
public class SomeClass {
  public SomeClass LastCreated { get; set;}
  public SomeClass CreatorObject {get; set;}
}
```

you could write something like:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("CreatorObject.LastCreated", this));
```